# modules.devname not found after updating process was cancelled

Tags: arch-linux, boot

I can't boot into my Arch system after updating was canceled in the middle of it.
When I'm trying to boot it shows this message

```
Warning: /lib/modules/4.19.25-1-lts/modules.devname not found - ignoring starting version 239
mount: /new_root: unknown filesystem type 'ext4'.
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell.
sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
[rootfs ]# _
```

When this message is shown I can't really type anything so I used live-usb.
My system has 3 partitions:

1. `boot` (~500mb);
2. `swap` (~16Gb) ;
3. another one that contains all the data and is the biggest one, I'll call this partition `home`.

In live-usb I've mounted:

1. `home` to `/mnt`
2. `boot` to `/mnt/boot`

Then I did these steps:

1. `arch-chroot /mnt`
2. `sudo pacman -S linux-lts` (I used lts before)
3. `mkinitcpio -p linux-lts`
4. `exit`
5. `reboot`

It didn't help.

One thing I noticed, after I arch-chroot'ed into the /mnt and typed `uname -r`, it showed me an older version that starts with 4.18. After I've performed steps 1, 2 and 3, I used `uname -r` again, and it still showed me the same old version 4.18..

What could be the source of this problem and how do I fix it?

UPDATE:
It happened to be that I was using custom initramfs and it wasn't updated. So I changed names of used initramfs back to initramfs-linux-lts.img (or something like that) in my grub.cfg file and system started to boot.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it.
It happened to be that I was using custom initramfs and it wasn't updated. So I changed names of used initramfs back to initramfs-linux-lts.img (or something like that) in my grub.cfg file and system started to boot.